# Lua has no class but dot operator?

Tags: lua

If Lua has no class, why does it have a dot operator?

Eg. In `string.find`, is `string` a class with static/class method `find`?

Comment: Dot operator is often used for getting a named field/member from a structure/record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, `find` is an entry in the *table* `string`

It is syntactic sugar for `string["find"]`

It could be defined like so:

```
local string = {
  "find" = function()
    -- find stuff
  end
}
```

or

```
local string = {}
string["find"] = function()
  -- find stuff
end
```

or

```
local string = {}
string.find = function()
  -- find stuff
end
```